# echo this given html code

Tags: php, html, combobox

Here is combobox select statement in html it is working fine :

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" <?php if($_REQUEST["id"]==$row["id"]) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $row["id"] ?></option>
```

I want to echo that html line

```
echo "<option value='". $row["id"] ."' <?php if(?>'".$_REQUEST["id"]<?php==?>$row["id"]'".<?php) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>'".$row["id"]."'</option>";
```

please correct the echo line .it is not working.

Comment: You can't have a if statement in a echo statement!

Comment: kindly correct my attempt according to html statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' " . (($_REQUEST['id'] == $row['id']) ? "selected": "") . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t use `if` in `echo`.

```
echo "<option value='". $row["id"] . "'" . ($_REQUEST["id"] == $row["id"] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>";
```

For more info see the `ternary operator` in [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-137).

Comment: it is not working properly combobox is giving id in combobox as:'1','2','3','4',...... it should be :1,2,3,4,

Comment: @panther You put a few ' too much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
echo "<option value='". $row["id"] ."' ".(($_REQUEST["id"] == $row["id"]) ? 'selected="selected"' : '').">".$row["id"]."</option>";
```

Comment: Also you have to put `()` around the full ternary operation, otherwise the value doesn't get dispayled.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$x= "";

if($_REQUEST['id']==$row['id'])
    $x= "selected='selected'";
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."' $x>".$row["id"]."</option>";
```

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.